# Where can I find the SAP System connection for connecting it with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I Have a code from the internet to automatically open SAP connection and log in, but I need the system name to set the connection between SAP system and VBA. I tried every entry what I could find in the logon window but all of them didn't work. And I searched a lot on the internet for this, but couldn't find any clear description where to find it. The code from the internet is as follows:

I have problems with this part of the code:

```
 Set SAPCon = SapGuiApp.OpenConnectionByConnectionString("SYSTEM", True)
```

I tried a lot of ID in place of SYSTEM and I got this error:

> The SAPgui component could not be instantiated.

```
Sub Download_Click()


Dim SapGuiApp As Object
Dim oConnection As Object
Dim session As Object
Dim SAPCon As Object, SAPSesi As Object
Dim SAPGUIAuto As Object, SAPApp As Object
Dim strUser As String
Dim strPW As String

  
strUser = Environ(" ") ' put your username of SAP
    
strPW = InputBox(Prompt:="Please Enter SAP PEA password:", Title:="Enter Password", Default:="********")
    
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

If SapGuiApp Is Nothing Then
    Set SapGuiApp = CreateObject("Sapgui.ScriptingCtrl.1")
    Set SAPApp = SapGuiApp.GetScriptingEngine
End If
  

If SAPCon Is Nothing Then
    Set SAPCon = SapGuiApp.OpenConnectionByConnectionString("SYSTEM", True) ' fill in the system
End If

If SAPSesi Is Nothing Then
   Set SAPSesi = SAPCon.Children(0)
End If
                
With SAPSesi
    .FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-MANDT").Text = "900"
    .FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").Text = strUser
    .FindById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").Text = strPW
    .FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-LANGU").Text = "EN"
    .FindById("wnd[0]").SendVKey 0
End With
```